# UIPageViewController makes UItalkeViewController "jump" on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uipageviewcontroller, ios13

I have an iOS app with an `UIPageViewController` that has 2 VCs:

1. classic `UIViewController` with "SOS screen"
2. `UITabBarViewController` with 3 tabs, first is `UITableViewController` with "Inbox"

In `UIPageViewController.viewDidLoad` I set the `UITabBarViewController` as the selected page.

This has worked fine in iOS 10, 11 and 12 but there is a problem with iOS 13 (built with Xcode 11)

When the `UITabBarViewController` is displayed it is off, the tab bar under the bottom safe area and the navbar over status bar. When I swipe to the `UIViewController` on the left and back to the `UITabBarViewController` it "jumps" and layouts itself properly:

[image]

Any ideas how to deal with it? I tried replacing the `UIPageViewController` with a custom `UIViewController` with both VC added to a scroll view but that causes other problems, breaks back gesture, etc. I need a way to fix the `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: You can use UIScrollview and add child view controller to it

Comment: That is exactly why I tried, written in my question. But it creates additional problems, like breaking the back navigation gesture,

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your ViewDidLoad function:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

It's a temporary fix, but it works.